# Worklight 5.0.5: Loader constraint violation when running Application Builder

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, classloader

during "Build All and Deploy" of a worklight application, I get the following error.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Worklight application builder". 
loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.iterateFiles(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Iterator;" 
the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) 
of the current class, com/worklight/builder/skins/impl/SkinBuilderImpl, 
and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) 
for resolved class, org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils, 
have different Class objects for the type leUtils.iterateFiles(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Iterator; 
used in the signature
```

Console output is

```
[2013-03-26 15:30:13]             Worklight Server started successfully on localhost:8080
[2013-03-26 15:30:13]             Activating Worklight project: AA...
[2013-03-26 15:30:28] FWLSE3005I: Application raw reports are disabled.
[2013-03-26 15:30:28] FWLST0010I: ====== Started server for project AA-project-customization; Worklight version=5.0.5.20130115-0926-developer-edition
[2013-03-26 15:30:28]             Activation done.
[2013-03-26 15:30:28]             Starting build process: application 'ap', all environments
```

I believe this bug is also discussed in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=465649 (read only)

For me it seems that this bug is pretty well reproducable.
It occurs every time another plugin is installed which contains/uses the org.apache.commons.io package

In my case I have an org.apache.commons.io_2.0.1.v201105210651.jar in my plugins folder (which was delivered by Sonar 2.4.0). It contains the same java classes as plugins\com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties_5.0.5.20130115-0926\target\dependency.

This is also a matter of ordering, as the error only occurs if Worklight is installed AFTER another org.apache.commons.io-using package was installed.

So I strongly believe that the problem is because there are different classes with the same (package) name (WHY ??)
I thought about setting classloader preferences (parent first etc). but I don´t know how and I don´t know where to set.

Just deleting the 3rd parties .jar´s only leads to other errors ...

Any hints are greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you try and see if this is reproducible with Worklight 5.0.6?

Comment: is reproducable, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, can you try and delete the commons.io plugin from your eclipse?
Hopefully, Sonar is using import-package and not require-bundle, and it will work, and this way Worklight won't have conflicts.

Comment: When deleting the org.apache.commons.io....jar, Worklight is running well, but Sonar plugin is obviously not able to start.

Comment: What do you mean by import-package and require-bundle, or better, how can I check that ? In the feature.xml of sonar I find nothing of both.

Comment: After copy org.apache.commons...jar again into the plugins folder, both are working - seems to be a matter of order.
Thank you very much for the suggestion, but as we speak about a managed environment with hundreds of users, and as many other plugins also use org.apache.common.io.*, this won´t be a reliable way......
????

Comment: sorry for the import-package/require-bundle question :-)
Sonar uses require-bundle :-(
Is there a way to tell Worklight to ignore its own .jars and use the other one instead ? Maybe something like classloading parent first ???